# Solr C# client that convert query result to object

Tags: solr

I am really new to solr.

I am wondering if there is C# client that allow me to convert solr query result to C# object?

I also have the solr schema xml but not sure how to convert it to C# class? Do i need to parse the xml?

Comment: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet

Comment: Thanks for share the info. I can not get it work.
I would like to query stub hub solr service. I am able to query using url, but i am not able to get solrnet to work. Can you lists few steps solrnet for query?

Comment: You can see the steps and much more information at https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/README.md

Answer (score 0):

There are many different Solr client implmentations for C#.

I have tried couple different ones, but only SolrNet worked with the current version.
(SolrNet version: SolrNet-0.4.0.2002.zip (843.53Kb), Solr version: 4.7.1)
[image: Solr Version]

First I have tried to use the NuGet package, but it turned out that it is outdated (was using deprecated API), get the newest version from here:

[Solr Net - Master](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=115887&tab=artifacts&buildTypeId=bt290)

Build the dlls and use them in your project.

You can find a nice tutorial here:

[SolrNet tutorial](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Basic-usage.md)

The only problem here is that these calls are now deprecated. Instead of Add method you should be calling the actually supported Commands. Add and the other derprecated methods already worked well but I don't think that you should rely on deprecetad calls.

Instead of these you can use the different Command classes representing the different Solr operations.

Example:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;
using SolrNet;
using SolrNet.Attributes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        class Product
        {
            [SolrUniqueKey("id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [SolrField("manu")]
            public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

            [SolrField("cat")]
            public ICollection<string> Categories { get; set; }

            [SolrField("price")]
            public decimal Price { get; set; }

            [SolrField("inStock")]
            public bool InStock { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Startup.Init<Product>("http://localhost:8983/solr");

            var p = new Product
            {
                Id = "SP2514M",
                Manufacturer = "Samsung Electronics Co. Ltd.",
                Categories = new[] {
            "electronics",
            "hard drive",
        },
                Price = 92,
                InStock = true,
            };

            var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrConnection>();            

            Dictionary<Product, double?> dict = new Dictionary<Product,double?>();
            dict.Add(p, 0);

            Console.WriteLine("-- Add products --");
            AddProducts(solr, dict);

            Console.WriteLine("-- Commit changes --");
            CommitChanges(solr);

            Console.WriteLine("--Query all documents --");
            QueryAll();

            Console.WriteLine("-- Delete all documents --");
            DeleteAll(solr);

            Console.WriteLine("-- Commit changes --");
            CommitChanges(solr);

            Console.WriteLine("--Query all documents --");
            QueryAll();

            Console.ReadKey();            
        }

        private static void DeleteAll(ISolrConnection solr)
        {

            SolrNet.DeleteParameters del = new DeleteParameters();
            SolrNet.Impl.FieldSerializers.DefaultFieldSerializer deffield = new SolrNet.Impl.FieldSerializers.DefaultFieldSerializer();
            SolrNet.Impl.QuerySerializers.DefaultQuerySerializer defquery = new SolrNet.Impl.QuerySerializers.DefaultQuerySerializer(deffield);

            SolrNet.Commands.Parameters.DeleteByIdAndOrQueryParam delpar = new SolrNet.Commands.Parameters.DeleteByIdAndOrQueryParam(Enumerable.Empty<string>(), SolrNet.SolrQuery.All, defquery);
            var delete = new SolrNet.Commands.DeleteCommand(delpar, del);
            string res = delete.Execute(solr);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(res);
        }

        private static void CommitChanges(ISolrConnection solr)
        {
            SolrNet.Commands.CommitCommand commit = new SolrNet.Commands.CommitCommand();
            string res = commit.Execute(solr);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(res);
        }

        private static void AddProducts(ISolrConnection solr, Dictionary<Product, double?> dict)
        {
            AddParameters par = new AddParameters();
            ISolrDocumentSerializer<Product> ser = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrDocumentSerializer<Product>>();
            SolrNet.Commands.AddCommand<Product> addProduct = new SolrNet.Commands.AddCommand<Product>(dict, ser, par);
            string res = addProduct.Execute(solr);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(res);
        }

        private static void QueryAll()
        {
            // Query all documents
            var query = SolrNet.SolrQuery.All;
            var operations = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Product>>();
            var Products = operations.Query(query);

            int i = 0;
            foreach (var product in Products)
            {
                i++;
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:\t {1} \t{2} \t{3}", i, product.Id, product.Manufacturer, product.Price);
            }

            if(i == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" = no documents =");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am very new to Solr too so my code may contain some flaws. Please help me spot them. Thank you.

See QueryAll method for querying and using the resulting objects.